# Using FDQuery.RecordCount to tell if the query is empty or not may return negative value in Delphi

Tags: database, delphi, firedac

I have an FDQuery on a form, and an action that enable and disable components according to its recordCount ( enabled when >0).

Most of times recordCount property return the actual count of records in the query. Sometimes, recordcount return negative value, but I can see records on a grid associated with the query. 
RecordCount returned values between -5 and -1, until now.

How can I solve this? why does it return negative values?

Comment: I think you need to show your code for readers to be able to help.  The problem is presumably data-related, so the code you show should include populating the FDQuery with data so that readers could reproduce the problem without needing access to your actual data.

Comment: @MartynA here is no need for exact sources. Using `RecordCount` is almost always a code smell. This function should be warning-marked `platform-specific` if not `experimental`. And with the behavior intention written in the first question line, it clearly was a bug.

Comment: What is your `RecordCountMode` setting? Can we have a minimal example for reproducing?

Comment: I Can not reproduce it too. It's always working for me. Rarely, in users machine, it produce this, so i let them report this bug to me with a button that send me information and I discovered that .RecordCount was negative.

Comment: I agree with @Arioch'The about the "smell" - it is a bad idea to depend on RecordCount returning an accurate or even sensible value.  So although it would be interesting to find how it is sometimes negative for your users, it seems to me that what you actually have here is an XY problem - whatever it is that you are trying to do, relying on RecordCount isn't the way to do it.  After all, some dataset types don't return a meaningful value at all, but that doesn't stop them being used in any gui situation I've come across.

Comment: @MartynA in this situations there is uncomfortable V-scroll bar behavior: the track size does not reflect the share of visible rows to all of them. But that is how it is.....

Comment: @Arioch'The: Yes, that's always been the case.  Istr that even in the BDE days, the scrollbar thumb could have positions (with some db types) of top/middle/bootom only.

Comment: @MartynA "with some db types" - with SQL types. Because in SQL it is fundamentally indeterminate how mane corteges you have in some arbitrary cursor, until you exhausted it. New rows can be created and added while you were reading other ones. It does not matter which library you use. Lest of some corner cases with some applicable hacks, this function can not be reliable on SQL no matter which proxy you use, ODBC or BDE, or DBX or ADO or FD or u name it.

Comment: You cannot rely on `RecordCount` unless you know what you are doing and configure your dataset to get that value. Use `DataSet.IsEmpty` to determine if is has records or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why does it return negative values?

That is not FireDAC specific, that is a normal behavior of all Delphi libraries providing `TDataSet` interface.

`TDataSet.RecordCount` was never warranted to work. It is even said in the documentation. This is a bonus functionality. Sometimes it may work, other times it will not. It is only expected to work reliably for non-SQL table data like CSV, DBF, Paradox tables and other similar ISAM engines.

> How can I solve this?

Relying on this function in the modern world is always a risky endeavor.
So you better design your program so that this function would never be used, or only in very few very specific scenarios.
Instead you should understand what question your program really asks to the library and then find a "language" to make this question by calling other functions, better tailored for your case.

---

Now tell me, when you search in Google how often do you read through up to 10th page, up to 100th page? Almost never, right? Your program users would also almost never scroll the data grid really far downwards. Keep this in mind.
You always need to show users first data and do it fast. But rarely the last data.

Now, three examples.

1) you read data from some remote server with slow internet. You can only read 100 rows per second. You grid has room to show 20 first rows. The rest user has to scroll by. In total the query can filter 10 000 rows for you.

If you just show those 20 rows to user - then it works almost instantly, it is only 0.2 seconds from when you start reading data to when you filled your grid and presented it to the user. The rest of the data would only be fetched if user would request it by scrolling (I am a bit simplifying here for clarity, I know about pre-caching `TDataset.Buffers`).

So if you call the `RecordCount` function what does your program do? It downloads ALL the records into your local memory where it counts them. And with such a speed it would take 10 000 / 100 = 100 seconds, more than a minute and a half.
Just by calling the `RecordCount` function you called `FetchAll` procedure and made your program response to the user not in 0.2 seconds but in 1m40s instead.
User would be very nervous waiting for that to finish.

2) Imagine you are fetching the data from some Stored Procedure. Or from a table, where another application is inserting the rows. In other words, that is not some static read-only data, that is live data that is being generated while you are downloading it.
So, how many rows are there then? This moment it is, for example, 1000 rows, in a second it would be 1010 rows, in two second it maybe would be 1050 rows, and so forth.
What is the One True Value when this value is being changed every now and then?

Oookey, you called `RecordCount` function, you `SetLength`-ed your array to the 1000, and now you read all the data from your query. But it takes some time to download the data. It usually is fast, but it never is instantaneous. So, for example, it took one second to you to download those 1000 rows the database query data into your array (or grid). But while you were doing it 10 more rows were generated/inserted, and your query is not `.EOF`ed, and you keep fetching rows #1001, #1002, ... #1010 - and you put them in the array/gris rows that just do not exist!

Would it be good?

Or would you cancel your query when you went out of the array/grid boundaries?
That way you would not have Access Violation.
But instead you would have those most recent 10 rows ignored and missed.

Is that good?

3) your query, when you debug it, returns 10 000 rows. You download them all into you program's local memory by calling `RecordCount` function, and it works like a charm, and you deploy it.

You client uses your program, and the data grows, and one day your query returns not the 10 000 rows, but 10 000 000.
Your program calls `RecordCount` function to download all those rows, it downloads, for example, 9 000 000 millions...
....and then it crashes with `Out Of Memory` error.

---

> enable and disable components according to its recordCount > 0

That is a wrong approach to get the data you do not ever need (exact quantity of rows), then discard it. The examples above show you how that makes your program fragile and slow.

All you really want to know is if there are any rows or none at all.
You do not need to count all the rows ad learn their amount, you only wonder whether the query is empty or not.

And that is exactly what you should ask by calling the `TDataSet.IsEmpty` function instead of `RecordCount`.

Comment: The question is about enabling or disabling components when count is more than 0. No one forces you to fetch all tuples. If you needed to know the overall count for a big dataset (never fetch to client ~10M tuples), simply use the `cmTotal` mode.

Comment: @Victoria actually, no. The question actually was "why FDQuery.RecordCount return negative values for some queries" and how to "solve this [apparent bug in FDQuery]". The rest ("what is your Z") is what we infer from the question description, but not what was actually asked

Comment: And that is the point, that calling `RecordCount` implies fetching all the data. Sure, in some exceptional cases `FDQuery` can circumvent it by one or another situation-specific hack. Sometimes. But not always. And coding your app relying upon a hope that FDQuery would always have some trick upon its sleeve to avoid default execution path is risky at best. Consider it a user-side YAGNI :-D

Comment: Wow! Didn't expect such a complete answer. Thanks!!

Comment: @Federico, but most of it is worthless to mention. Why would one fetch millions of tuples (well, in live mode it would make sense). Still, if you use `cmTotal` mode, FireDAC simply issues a SQL command to get the count.

Comment: @Victoria:  I agree about "most of it".  The OP hasn't explained why he is relying on RecordCount in the first place.

Comment: @Victoria, because enumerating is the only *universal method* to count things. Unless you have some narrow niche hacks (and that niche is loosely defined by lots of different factors), to count the rows you have to enumerate them.

Comment: `FireDAC simply issues a SQL command to get the count.` - LOL!  And then we should insert new records using `select MAX(ID)+1 from tablename` instead of using those clumsy gap-ful sequences/generators.  I would not even say that even with such a command it still is an extra potentially slow work. Yeah, now it is not the program downloading all rows, it is the server fetching all rows from non-cached HDD. Only to remove the useful needed data from its cache, and send as the value we do not need.

Comment: @Arioch'The:  Sorry, but I think your comments are getting more and more off the point.

Comment: Dmitry is not an idiot. Why would he query `MAX`? It's as simple as that if you setup the `cmTotal` mode, FireDAC executes `SELECT COUNT` command to get the total number of potentionally fetched tuples (no tuple needs to be fetched though).

Comment: Why not? How is SELECT MAX worse than SELECT COUNT? Both are fragile hacks working perfectly in one conditions and failing in other, and those conditions are the same. SELECT MAX is better though: it is faster because does force server to trash its cache by redundant fetching tonnes of tuples from HDD.

Comment: (re-posted to edit) @MartynA which point? The point in this subtopic is that SELECT COUNT somehow is good and universal approach. But this approach is only correct when SELECT MAX approach is. They are either both correct or both not. And even when they are, SELECT MAX is better one of the two, cause it does not create performance hit of SELECT COUNT

Comment: XYZ problems was identified and solved. This is a side-story now. Victoria's point is that there is no need to change that XY approach because `SELECT COUNT(*) from ( -original-query-) ` is somehow both reliable and cost-free approach to check if you can find one first row into the cursor or not.

Comment: Im not sure how MAX is even relevant to **counting** records. Think about it for a second...

Comment: @kobik it is different functionality, surely. But it is the same as COUNT in respect to "when we should expect correct/incorrect reliable/unreliable results of stmt execution"

Comment: I found same problem.  TFDQuery containing data but recordcount shows zero.  It does only happen to me (Postgres SQL 11 – Delphi XE6 – Firedac) when I just added the record in cached updates mode, so that the database is not yet aware of the new record created.  I do not see if the question was on this situation.  Anyone has detected recordcount failing in any other situations?

Comment: I believe it is very extended among software developers to find out if there are records in a table by asking for the count(*) and this is really a bad habit as  Arioch 'The illustrates (You just want to know if there is one record and DB Engine goes through all the records in the database, doesn't necessarily recovers all the data, but it still takes a lot of Endeavour when for most cases as it is the case in the question above seems not to be needed at all (He just one to know if recordcount is 0 or > 0).  I think it is always good to remind as all why we should never do that.

Comment: @Atreide two problems are: 1: users want reasonable scrollbars - and that requres knowing `count` - not perhaps accurate, but give or take 10% is ok. 2: In Delphi 5 (1999) there was no `TDataset.IsEmpty` function. Programmers were *supposed* to use `TDataset.BOF and TDataset.EOF` as a substitute, but most code examples only shown `.EOF` and not `.BOF` and i am not sure this was ever documented. So they went easy was with `RecordCount <> 0` instead (and -1 <> 0 :-D ). I do not remember which Delphi version introduced `.IsEmpty` function, but to that year internet was all full with count abuse

Comment: This is not the worst thing though. Some... UK? site of Delphi recipes was solving the problem of correctly comparing floating point values via `FloatToStr`.... It was given as the proper way there...

Comment: Well I was myself using recordCount to find out if there were records in the database.  (On my discharge I have to say that I am working on updating and old software development) I was actually thinking that asking for the TFDQ recordcount would just check for the records that were already in the recordset but not go to the database to find out.  It was when I found out that it did not recognise the just added record and I read your post that I realised.  So that is why I wrote the comment.  To remind people like me why it is a bad habit.

Comment: By the way, and assumed is not the matter in this post.  I did face trouble on comparing floating point numbers in Delphi (XE6) and I found that comparing the strings (FloatToStr) would easily go round the problem.  But I agree, certainly does not look like the right way to do it.  And I am certainly open to any suggestions.  I saw some posts about defining functions to compare float numbers with a very small difference, but I thought that converting to string and compare would mean much less effort and the result looks right.  Probably wrong though.

Comment: @Atreide this is sadly a total (as in everyone's) lack of education. Problems with float comparison come from basic mathematics: notion of infinite periodic fraction and it's equicalency with converging geometric sequence, then notion of primary numbers and factorization. This means we can not have exact representation of our decimal floats in binary computers. The problem is obvious if mathematics and computers implementations are studied. But if the approach is to make cheap^W labor cost optimized "works once when you sell it off" solutions - then we have it...

Comment: In Delphi one can just tap F1 over the `double` datatype and go http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Double there go to "simple types" and down there you have the dedicated pages "About Floating-Point Arithmetic" and "Floating-Point Comparison Routines". Problem lies with "unknown unknowns". One just doesn't think the float comparison has to be done different way, if one's studying mathematics and physics failed to teach the real world is not ideal but always is some non-exact approximation... However, after you learnt of the problem, the solution is one F1 keystroke away

Comment: Concerning Mathematics and floating point representation.  Well I am afraid I have studied some.  But I have worked with some other programming languages too, and when I ask if two floating point numbers are the same and in order to avoid trouble I do round them, and once rounded I put them in a text box and they are exactly the same, and Delphi keeps on saying they are not.  Well three points for mathematical theoretical, but I am just trying to get a program to work.  Pascal should never have been chosen for a management software developing tool...That I agree.

Comment: If I was on time I would have rather used Currency instead of Double.  But there is a lot of software already developed and well this FoatToStr seemed like a fine way to surround the problem.  I agree the right solution would been using currency type as I read here and there to avoid this floating point calculation problem.  Too late for me.  Hope in time for someone else.

Comment: `and once rounded` - that is it, rounded. Same here, round and compare rounded values. Or, actually, there ALREADY IS a function of compare-floats-rounded-to-some-threshold. "trying to get a program to work" is very vague idea. It spans from understanding what and why program does to hardcoding "correct answer" and returning it always regardless of input. In retrospect, perhaps, there should never be a binary operator of comparing floats, to start with, only ternary ones. Don't create illusion of safety, don't pull wool over programmer's eyes. But perhaps it is too late now.

Comment: It is funny to remember that early database systems, from SQL to DBF, did not have "true" floating numbers, they had fixed-point decimals, and stored them using BCD or outright text representations. So you may say thta early compute systems, before world settled byte should be 8 bit, etc, were founded upon "FloatToStr" at least for storing/loading/transfering data, if not for calculation. Still, binary equality comparison over floats was bad anti-safe choice... `Hope in time for someone else` hardly so, it should be (and used to be) present in every programing intro books/courses, to no avail.

Comment: Having a number and an external representation of the number might be of fantastic interest if you are in deep math calculation.  No matter where you want the number to appear you never loose the root of the  number in case you need to do any further calculations.  I am just working on regular management development, and when I round a value, the result that I want is the value rounded..  I really have no need to keep the real value of the number.  That is why I use FloatToStr, because what I want is the rounded value.  Which is the way it works for the most of programming languages.

Comment: From SQL to DBF and before SQL on navigational database management systems and before that on ISAM files management.  Never heard of DBMS that compares two floating point numbers that printed are the same and comparison throws any difference.  To me this is very much "Delphi specifics".  And from ISAM files to Oracle or Postgres I did not find any inconvenience with floating point numbers till now.

Comment: SQL simulates old "textual" numbers by explicitly declaring numbers as fixed-point `DECIMAL(N,m)` instead of floating point. But no, this started long before Delphi. Perhaps even before C. Of course, some language/RTL may just assume some allowed deviation and secretly do non-exact comparison with some fixed threshold, rather than informing programmer and giving him a choice. Maybe some even did. Afterall error-free programming using `try ... except end;` is also a well-known phenomenon, and there was quite popular MySQL3 too.

Comment: `That is why I use FloatToStr, because what I want is the rounded value` - in other words you want an integer value, measured in some small atoms. Like you can use 1/1000th of Ruble or 1/1000th of USD, etc. This is easier with `Currency` type but you could code the same explicitly with any integer datatype. Plus, there is that specific "financial rounding" which is different from all the mathematical three. All in all, "don't do finances in floats" is well-known adage... And i beleive it also predates Delphi, just a common sense.

Comment: Exactly.  That is what I want.  Currency would have been much better choice than double for financials. Thank you very much.

Comment: On the other hand, not that I am an expert in Computational history or anything like that but old enough to see it personally.  I guess you are right. 
 This certainly started much before C (Before I ever heard of C at least).  I believe it was Pascal language that introduced many of this mathematical matters in a programming language.  A scientific language designed by the scientific community.

Comment: Well a minute to check the Wikipedia and it seems Pascal is not considered a scientific language at all, in fact they call it General purpose language.  When I started hearing about turbo pascal in the 80's I swear it was the scientific language by default.  "A scientific language designed by the scientific community" would be typical phrase that came with it.  I read now that it was designed by computational teacher to teach his students about  structured programming.  No relation to the scientific community at all.  I just know I don´t know.

Comment: Well, Pascal was educational language instead of clunky Basic. For real use Wirth proposed Modula-2/Oberon/Component Pascal. The latter has the sugar i envy: `if x is y` does the actual type cast :-) But while Wirth was designiong his "serious" languages Pascal already gained too much inertia, trapped in its own success. p-Machine, then Turbo and the game was over. TopSpeed company never got steam...  However to quote Pascal report 1974: *A value of type real is an element of the **implementation-defined** subset of real numbers.* But pure hardware performance of then processors meant CPU

Comment: implementation details would leak into abstractions of languages, not vice versa. p-USCD virtual machines were eclipsed by "close to metal" Turbo. LISP machines were extinguished, etc. "designed by the scientific community" that is true, however not every scientific device is easy to use and generic of use. You may consider Scala, in some sense designed by people of the same hive as Wirth, and you can run crazy just trying to grasp their type system :-D However specificall on Pascal, it was designed as a tool to educate, to introduce into the trade. And it was so good at that, it transcended

Comment: `designed by computational teacher to teach his students` - so that is NOT scientific community in your book? preserving and spreading of knowledge is the key function of science.Comparing to the wild jungles of B/BCPL/C - throw all new features you heard today of against the wall and see what sticks - Pascal was really carefully designed to be minimal yet enough. Overachieved, actually, and suddenly got used to real deals and almost monopolized by Borland. Which in tern inhibited its evolution.

Comment: Yes I agree. A teacher is certainly related to scientific community.  You are right.  And thank you for the accurate and really explanatory comments.  Interesting matter how did programming languages evolve.  He makes a tool for his students while he is concentrating on the real language development and it is the tool for the students that we are all still programming with.  Kinda Funny though.

Comment: I have what could well be the obvious question next.  In order to check if there are records in the database, I check not ... isEmpty.  Ok.  Now... 
When I want to go through al the records in the tfdqquery I do not go for i := 1 to FDQ_Name.RecordCount I go While not FDQ_Name.EOF.  Right?  
Now the question: When I want to know how many records in the TFDQuery (In the filtered TFDQuery that I am using in the Form), not in the database, (I am working with cached updates and may be none yet).  I have to loop on all them and get the count or there is some specific TFDQuery property for it?

Comment: @Atreide  - That i just don't know, i did not have buy AnyDAC for Delphi XE2 which we ended with. The problem is then WHY exactly you need that number and WHAT that number wouuld ever mean? No it does NOT mean "number of records in the database", because this number keeps chaning every split second as other ocmputers keep inserting/deleting rows. Actually, while you are looping through all those `while not EOF do begin ... Next; End;` this number might already change few times. So if you measured the number before the loop - this value might get obsolete & wrong when you read just the 2nd row!

Comment: So, basically, and i am being purist here, copy all the data from the database into your local storage, be it in-memory `TList<SomeRecords>` or `TClientDataset` or DBF file or anything, and along that copying you can count the ...ahem, count. And then the number would be acucrate, cause no one else can mess with you local and isolated copy of the rows.

Comment: In the code I am working with, I started checking for TFDQuery.RecordCount and I found many, most likely Master Detail checking. Master and Detail maintained in same form and when user pushes Accept button often there are validations and/or calculations among the detail records (Working on XE6 with FireDac against PostgreSQL 11.8 database, with range based master detail relations defined and cached updates managing) and really there is small chance for concurrence trouble so I guess I got somehow overconscientious on this RecordCount matter, and I made the question.

Comment: I got mixed up with concepts I am affraid, actually records are posted to the database and the count goes right with recordcount, and for the small chance that any other user was trying to update the same records I better use some locking. Thank you anyhow because your answer made it very clear for me suddenly and sorry about the really not much sense question.

Comment: @Atreide we all have that simple "single user me the developer and single computer the developer's station" mental picture when designing most of the program. The idea that "count of records in a query" is not some persistent data is counter-intuitive. And perhaps on many servers it even would be. It is about "cursor stability" levels. In Firebird 2 and below simple `insert into table X select * from X` would lead to infinite table growing. Which is expected in retrospect for lazy-evaluating slim engine FB is, but counter-intuitive. Maybe PG "latches" the select against parallel ins/del dunno

Comment: Yes, really the origin of my trouble with recordcount was (I believe) because of not posting a record, so I had one record in the TDBGrid _not yet posted_ and recordcount was saying 0.  That is what brought me to this page _In which I learned a lot I have to say_ But in the very specific datasets that I work with (Only the detail records related to a specific master) being a small application with few users concurrently working and very rarely on the same maintenance, I believe I can trust recordcount when I want to know the number of records in the Dataset. Locking records solves any trouble

Comment: ... Locking records would solve any further trouble I believe... (I had no more space in previous comment but actually it was more like something I still have to confirm)

Comment: @Atreide that also relies on a purpose of counting. To reiterate, if you pre-allocate an array then a "one off" error might be critical. If you just tweak scroll bars then plus-minus 10% is accurate enough. I do not say that `RecordCount` has zero use. I say that **by default, a priori** developer has to consider it useless (impractical, unreliable, slow, etc), **until** he would prove that in his specific environment and for his specific goals it works, and until he takes the burden to keep checking it maintaining the program in future. I'm not against hacks, i'm for realizing they are hacks.

Comment: Totally agree, that is what I mean by "I still have to confirm".  I believe that locking the records and working with very discrete and specific sets of records will do the job.  If I was starting this development I would seriously consider alternatives to RecordCount, but is not so.  I did find nice regular expression to substitute (.*) (.*\S)\.Recordcount?\s*>\s*0 by (\1) Not (\2).IsEmpty And made my life easier for the first case, but the rest of recordcounts I have, it would be manually modifying.  Only problem I had so far was concerning the posting of records and I have to rely on that.

Comment: *And that is exactly what you should ask by calling the TDataSet.IsEmpty function instead of RecordCount.* TDataset.IsEmpty() code: `Result := FActiveRecord >= FRecordCount;`.

Comment: @Alekcvp ...which proves the point. Notice that this code you quoted explicitly **avoids using `RecordCount`**. Note also, not all database libraries are inherinting from `TDataSet`, some provide similar API while having different ancestry, using `IsEmpty` you would request optimized behaviour and the ball would be in library's park to provide it or fail it. But when your application requests a library for a non-optimized function, then the ball is in your park.

Comment: @Arioch'The [`Data.DB.TDataSet.Eof`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Eof) *Indicates whether a dataset is positioned at the last record. If Eof is true, the current record is unequivocally the last row in the dataset.* **Eof is true when an application: Opens an empty dataset.** *Tip: If both Eof and Bof are true, the dataset or range is empty.*

Comment: @Alekcvp Sure, and it was om my comment above  of *Apr 23, 2021 at 11:26*

Comment: @Arioch'The *but most code examples only shown .EOF and not .BOF and i am not sure this was ever documented* - it is, see my comment. The bof check is not required if the dataset has just been opened.

Comment: @Alekcvp not that is NOT documented. By the same logic it would've been documented if written in advertisement leaflet in Delphi box, that everyone throws to gartbage without reading. Documentation is what programmers find when he searches for a specific problem. Would there be a full paragraph of text in `.RecordCount` suggesting against its use and pointing at the way to go - it would've been one, and code examples and FAQs would not today be reeking of this abuse. Perhaps, compiuler could step up and give warnings on comparisons of `.RecordCount` with zero - it did not

Comment: There was a story, apocryph?, that once Microsoft C++ decided to speed up things and made there `free()` (like `FreeMem` here) not free the memory, but onlyu put it to some list, that programmer had to process infrequently by a MS-custom function. They documented it better, they added the tip to the `free()` dunction help page. Still, programs were crashing with out of virtual memory, and not even MS C++ tech support knew about this change. But, from a "Legalist Genie" point of few the documentation was there, just ut was not documented there is documentation to read.

Comment: @Arioch'The By "documented" I meant the state of the EOF, not the RecordCount.

Comment: @Alekcvp this goes down to "what documentation is". Is it a fineprint perfectly hidden, so the user breaks thing and becomes a natural prey to lawyers? Then yes, it was documented. Is it a guide to help user properly solve practical problems? Thne it was not. It is a PKUNZIP.ZIP case, you only find this tip after you already learnt what was written there from other sources. If you did not had a priori knowledge - you would not find it. That is just the fact of life, given how vastly `RecordCount` abuse is spred. With adequate documentation there's be no such pandemic.

Comment: @Arioch'The [TDataSet.RecordCount](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.RecordCount): *For Query-type datasets, the RecordCount contains the total number of records that have currently been fetched.* So, the negative values are bugs.

Comment: @Alekcvp They changed it some day between 2008 and 2012. But compare with `TDataLink.RecordCount`, `TCustomSQLDataSet.RecordCount` - and that non mentioning ADO - so it is all kinda flaky. P.S. Also, is there a warranty explicitly stated, that there always WOULD be at least a single row fetched (or attempted) before you tried to read any of field values? For optimization reason the dataset would rpobably try to fetch first `.BufferCount` of rows, still i wonder if some lib could legitimately return zero for a just opened query :-)